# redirect command output

Tags: shell, powershell, redirect, cmd

folks,
 I need to redirect command output to 2 files, in one file redirect stdout stream,
to another file redirect stderr stream. 
Is it possible to do in cmd, PowerShell on windows ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For powershell**

Let us say you have `my.ps1` like below:

```
"output"
Write-Error "error output"
exit 1
```

You can do:

```
.\my.ps1 2>stderr.txt | Tee-Object -file stdout.txt
```

You get stdout and stderr in the corresponding files.

More on Tee-Object:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347705.aspx

More on capturing all streams:

https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=297055&SiteID=99

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, it's right, but it's not that i find. I am writing program on C# that execute hg(Mercurial) through "WScript.shell",  how can i redirect output from there to 2 files, stdout and stderr ?

Comment: The original question was a bit unclear. Are you looking for this: [Windows Scripting Host (WSH) output redirection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278411)?

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell you can redirect standard output and error using the well known redirection operators `>`, `>>`, `2>`, `2>>`.

First make sure to set:

```
$erroractionpreference.value__=1
```

Then use redirection.

**Examples:**

`ls C:\ 2> stderror.txt > stdoutput.txt # write output on stdoutput.txt`

`ls foo 2> stderror.txt > stdoutput.txt # write output on stderror.txt unless foo exists`